# How to add text scrim in android

Tags: user-interface, android-layout, textview, imageview

**Objective :**
Overlay a text header, on top of an image. Something like this:

[image]

**Current Implementation :** I have a `CardView`, which consists of an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. I can put the text on top of the image, but I can't get that background scrim.

**Problem :** I need that background scrim, because without it the text is illegible on top of the image.

**Stack :** Android L

**Layout XML :**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/event_cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eventImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="eventImage"
            android:src="@drawable/sample"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Event Name" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Would appreciate any pointers on some help with this.

Comment: Could you post your own results (code and a screenshot would be of help)so far , for side by side comparsion of what you actually trying to achieve

Comment: @AditLal: I figured this out. It was quite simple actually. Use "android:background" and that acts as the scrim.

Answer (score 24):

Create a [shape drawable resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) that only include the XML namespace as an attribute for the shape. Depending on whether you want a solid or gradient scrim, will change the content of the shape element.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- The content of the shape will go here. -->

</shape>
```

If you want a solid scrim, add a solid element to your shape element with the attribute `android:color` set to some color with alpha.

```xml
<solid
    android:color="#88000000"/>
```

If you want a gradient scrim, add a gradient element with the following attributes from the android namespace: `angle`, `centerY`, `startColor`, `centerColor`, `endColor`, and `type`. If you want to follow [the Material Design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/imagery.html#imagery-ui-integration), like in the image you provided, the gradient element should have the following values:

```xml
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerY="0.3"
    android:startColor="#CC000000"
    android:centerColor="#66000000"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:type="linear"/>
```

It is a good idea to have these values extracted and placed in the relevant resource files, like `dimens.xml` and `colors.xml`, so that the scrim can change depending on the configuration of the device.

Once you have the scrim saved as a shape drawable resource, you can add it to the background of your `TextView` using the `android:background` attribute. Using the `TextView` that you provided and assuming that you named the scrim file `scrim.xml`, the modification would be the following:

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Event Name"
    android:background="@drawable/scrim"/>
```